# Limit to infinity of a Sum

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} L_N = \lim_{N \to \infty} \Delta x \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} f(x_j) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{4}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} (\frac {35}{2}[\frac{4j}{N} + 4])$$
$f(x) = (\frac{35}{2}(x+4))$  , $x_j = \frac{4j}{N}$  , $\Delta x = \frac{4}{N}$

I need to find the limit of $L_{N}$ at $[0,4]$ I've found $x_j$ and $\Delta x$ but am having trouble finding the limit.

Comment: This slightly reminds Riemann sums for definite integrals, but many things are unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=\frac{35}{2} (x+4)$, $f$ is continous on $[0,4]$, hence integrable there.
Divide $[0,4]$ into n equal part, i.e.
$$0=\frac{4*0}{n}<\frac{4*1}{n}<...<\frac{4(n-1)}{n}<\frac{4*n}{n}=4$$
Note that each subinterval has width $$\Delta x=\frac{4}{n}$$
Pick $\xi_i=\frac{4}{n}$, we can form the following Riemann sum
$$\sigma=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\xi_i)\Delta x$$
As $n \to \infty$, $\Delta x \to 0$, therefore
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\xi_i)\Delta x=\int_{0}^{4}f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

A more basic way of handling this is to write the sum as $\frac{280}{N^2}\sum_{j= 0}^{N-1} j+ \frac{280}{N}\sum_{j= 0}^{N-1} 1$.

Adding 1 a total of N times (from 0 to N-1) is, of course, N so the second sum is just 280 which is independent of N.  The first sum involves $\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} j= \sum_{j= 1}^{N-1} j$ (since the j= 0 term is just 0).  It is well known, and easy to prove, that $\sum_{j= 1}^M j= \frac{M(M+1)}{2}$ so $\sum_{j= 0}^{N-1} j= \frac{(N-1)N}{2}= \frac{N^2- N}{2}$.  $\frac{280}{N^2}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} j= \frac{280(N^2- N)}{2N^2}= 140- \frac{140}{N}$. That obviously goes to 140 as N goes to infinity.  Thus the initial limit is 280+ 140= 420.